# How to apply BDI tag inside css code?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I'm using `bdi` tag in several places in my page.

I want to know if there is a way to apply this tag as part of a css class in some way ?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to make this solution for drop down lists items, so the `bdi` functionality will fixed my problem with the brackets inside it:

That's what I tried so far:

```
<form:select id="locale" path="locale">                 
    <c:forEach items="${locales}" var="loc">
        <c:choose>                          
        <c:when test="${loc.key == currentLocale}">
            <option itemValue="key" value="${loc.key}" selected><bdi><div>${loc.value}</div></bdi></option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <option itemValue="key" value="${loc.key}"><bdi><div>${loc.value}</div></bdi></option>
        </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>                                     
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi#See_also

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide code you have tried so far.

Comment: @MatějŠtágl I guess, not all the posts in SO needs code. As in this question, OP has no hint on how to achieve the thing, so how could he produce the code for that problem. Just a thought.

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class. HTML has classes. CSS has class selectors. It's really unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to target bdi elements with CSS (which would use a type selector, not a class selector)? Are you asking how to how to apply the semantics that the bdi element provides with a CSS rule (rule, not class)?

Comment: I meant to say class selectors, and I'm asking about how to apply the semantics of bdl element to a css selector

Comment: @roeygol can you please show a code snippet of one of the text you are using inside `bdi` just to be clear about what type of texts you are handling with `bdi` - any unicode, arabic, or something else??

Comment: @RakibulIslam using mainly Arabic and languages like that which are also presented with brackets which make my data wrong

Answer (score 1):

### Specify text direction through CSS

Use `direction: ltr` and `direction: rtl` for this. You need to figure out the text direction of each option. Then specify the right option class:

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}

.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<select class="rtl">
  <option class="ltr">English (United States)</option>
  <option class="rtl">(ישראל) עִברִית</option>
</select>
```

This fixes your braces problem I think. I guess you want all the options to have the text right-aligned. I tried to make that work but could not find a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property `unicode-bidi` which when used along with `direction` property, gives the flavor of html `bdi`.

Demo snippet below shows a working example:

```css
.bdi {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option class="bdi">English (United States)</option>
  <option class="bdi">(ישראל) עִברִית</option>
</select>
```

If you need more information or other use cases in this regard, here is the MDN page links of [unicode-bidi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) and [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction).

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know how to manage this solution for drop down lists, i'm having the problem also there

Comment: Can you please add the codes of your dropdown lists that is not working, it will be easier to debug then.

Comment: @roeygol Follow the edits I have made, if it helps. I'm not sure whether you are asking this or something else. Let me know.

Comment: I changed it to be `unicode-bidi: plaintext;` and it fixed the selected item and not the items in the list (when the list is opened), so we in half of the way

Comment: @roeygol Actually, I can't understand the actual output you are expecting. May be some graphic or any demo texts can make it clear.

Comment: A picture is added in the original picture

Comment: @roeygol Good job, now it is more clear. But, I can see that the texts are already in right to left direction, but what is your expected output? And also, which language is that, you can provide some demo text in your post so that we can test it. And have you tried my previous edited solution, I thought that would solve your issue.

Comment: The language it's Hebrew, and you can see that the selected is presented well while the item from the drop down is not (English item). Expected is to fix the bracket for the English item

Comment: @roeygol Right, now I'm clear. I'll let you know if I can solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177652/discussion-between-rakibul-islam-and-roeygol).